# Principles of mathematical Analysis by Rudin Theorem 1.32

Tags: real-analysis, logic

The theorem states:

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R$ s.t.

\begin{align}
&(a)\; \forall\alpha\in\mathbb R, \alpha\in A\;\underline\lor\alpha\in B\\
&(b)\; A\cap B=\emptyset\\
&(c)\; A\ne\emptyset\land B\ne\emptyset\\
&(d)\;\; \alpha\in A\;\land\;\beta\in B\implies\alpha < \beta\\
& \implies\exists!\gamma\in\mathbb R\;s.t.(\alpha\leq\gamma\;(\forall\alpha\in A))\;\land\;(\beta\geq\gamma\;(\forall\beta\in B))
\end{align}

**Proof**

Suppose there are two numbers $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ for which conclusion holds, and $\gamma_1<\gamma_2.$ Choose $\gamma_3$ such that $\gamma_1<\gamma_3<\gamma_2$ (This is possible by thm 1.29).
Then $\gamma_3<\gamma_2$ implies $\gamma_3 \in A$, whereas $\gamma_1<\gamma_3$ implies $\gamma_3 \in B$. This contradicts $(b)$. There is thus at most one number $\gamma$ with the desired properties.

Proof continues....

*Question*: Author states that $\gamma_3<\gamma_2$ implies $\gamma_3 \in A$. But $(d)$ states:
 $$[\alpha\in A, \beta \in B] \implies \alpha< \beta,$$
which is not same as $$\alpha < \beta \implies [\alpha\in A, \beta \in B] .$$

Can someone explain logic underlying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you meant to write $\gamma_1 < \gamma_3 < \gamma_2$.

The proof presents it a little tersely, but it's actually arguing from the properties of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, specifically, for $i = 1, 2$,
\begin{align}
\alpha \in A &\implies \alpha \le \gamma_i \\
\beta \in B &\implies \gamma_i \le \beta,
\end{align}
or more specifically, their contrapositives.
Since $\gamma_1 < \gamma_3$, we have
$$\gamma_3 \not\le \gamma_1 \implies \gamma_3 \notin A \implies \gamma_3 \in B.$$
Similarly,
$$\gamma_3 < \gamma_2 \implies \gamma_2 \not\le \gamma_3 \implies \gamma_3 \notin B \implies \gamma_3 \in A.$$
But this means that
$$\gamma_3 \in A \cap B = \emptyset,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: You are  correct about $\gamma_1<\gamma_3<\gamma_2$.  

Seems like it comes with experience to see such things.   

Thank you.